# How to set up custom dimension value with google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

I am trying to extract the client-id for each of my page views, but have a hard time following the documentation. I have already set up a custom dimension in the analytics admin, which requires me paste the following code to my platform:

```
var dimensionValue = 'SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE';
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
```

What I don't understand is what should the `dimensionValue` be here?

From [google analytics doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie), I get the following which seems to be the method to get the clientId for my website:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

Then how should I relate the clientId here with the dimensionValue? Should I pass the clientId variable to the previous dimensionValue? I don't know about javascript thus not sure how this should be set up. Now what I am currently doing is this:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
ga('set', 'dimension1', clientId);
```

No idea if it is going to work? Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks right to me... Give it a whirl and see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one Google Analytics property on your site, you can use the below code to populate the client id value and set it to dimension1. Make sure that when you are setting the value you set it before calling the pageview send call. Otherwise, you will need to fire an event in order to send the dimension value.

```
var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
ga('set', 'dimension1', clientId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I end up using. I just need to move the `set` and `send` command into the function, otherwise the commands will be executed without clientId being defined beforehand since the function is asynchronous:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', clientId);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer necessary to store clientId in a custom dimension.
Google Analytics has made ga:clientId available through the API.

Comment: Is this a white list feature? I could not find any references to this. Be great if you could post a link, thanks.